# jQuery PanZoom: How to limit panning by some percentage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery.panzoom

Is there a way to limit panning maybe by 50% of the image. For example while panning the image, if 50% of image is out of screen/panning area, then stop panning in that direction.

Check this [demo](http://ariutta.github.io/svg-pan-zoom/demo/limit-pan.html) for the behaviour which I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Just use inverted containment
http://timmywil.github.io/jquery.panzoom/demo/#inverted-contain and adjust the whitespace around the element to stop when panning in a particular direction.

Comment: Although it seems to work in some cases like on the demo page, it seems to be buggy. I could not get it to work in my context, and event contain: true is buggy since version 1.3.4. See my post here about this: https://github.com/timmywil/jquery.panzoom/issues/283#issuecomment-255447634

Comment: Yea, not working well for me at all either. Hopefully he fixes soon... do you know if there's a way to cancel panning from the `panzoomstart` event?